# Connecting to MSSQL from Kettle PDI

Tags: pentaho, kettle, ntlm, pdi, dbeaver

I am trying to configure a connection to MSSQL server in Pentaho Kettle and force it to use NTLM authentication. 
I have successfully connected to the said database server i dBeaver, using NTLM auth method.

[Here is how I configured dBeaver connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDA7C.png)

However i try in Kettle, it gives me login name failure. dBeaver connection is configured to use mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8 driver (Native mode i Kettle). I have also tried to use jDTS driver to no success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Driver mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8.jar is going into data-integration\lib\
2. dll mssql-jdbc_auth-8.2.1.x64.dll (packaged together with driver) is
   going to data-integration\libswt\win64\
3. Start Spoon
4. Configure mssql connection as MS SQL Server(Native) with pwd and
   username without domain
5. Check “use integrated security” checkbox
6. In “options”  configure properties:

authenticationScheme --- NTLM; 
domainName --- your domain name

Try test connection!